# definition of circular/directional random variable

Tags: statistics, measure-theory

Good day,

i wanted to ask you to check my definition of circular random variable since i have never seen any.
So based on the assumption, that difference between linear and circular variables, is that c.r.v. takes values on the unit circle, that my variation of its definition is the following:

Definition: Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P)$ be a probability space, and let $\Theta:\Omega\rightarrow[0,2\pi)$ is such mapping, that $\forall \theta \in [0,2\pi)$ is valid 
$$\{\omega \in \Omega: 0<\Theta(\omega)\leq\theta \}=X^{-1}((0,\theta])\in\mathcal{A},$$
then we call $\Theta$ a circular random variable (or it´s $\mathcal{A}$-measurable function).

Is it correct, or is there some kind of mistake? cause, it seems pretty good to me.

Thanks for any comment.
Have a good day to all.

Comment: Seems fine, though I wouldn't really isolate this definition like this (it is just a random variable on $[0,2\pi)$ regarded as a sub-measure space of $\mathbb{R}$).

Comment: I don't think there is such a thing as a linear random variable or a circular random variable, at least not when the variable maps $\Omega$ to a subset of the real numbers. You _can_ take a variable that maps $\Omega$ to an interval and use it to define a random point on a line segment or a random point on the circumference of a circle. It doesn't matter what the interval is; any interval can be interpolated to select one of the desired points at random.

Comment: That sounds good. Could i ask you to write it in more details?